# Azure Media Service - No compatible source found for this media

Tags: azure, live-streaming, azure-media-services

I'm trying to use Azure Media Services to live stream an IP cam through OBS.

So I'll try to describe my setup.
I added a new Media Service via the Azure Portal.
It has it's own storage account.
Still in the portal in that Media Service I choose 'Browse Channels'.
Here I create a new channel, I tried Live Encoding and Pass Through. I get the same result with both.
So the channel is created, I wait until it is started and I open that blade of the channel.

I copy the Primary Injest endpoint and copy that in the settings of OBS, as a stream key I use the name of the channel/account (I picked the same name for both) and start streaming from OBS.

I then click more in the top right of the blade and pick 'Watch preview'.
A new blade opens with a player with an error in it.

[image: Preview Blade]

When I copy the playback url and open it in VLC it plays correctly for roughly 30 seconds.

Now if I add a new Program back in the Channel Blade it adds it, and starts it up. When started I open the Program Blade and get a loading screen which doesn't end. Looking in the network tab of the developer tools, no errors are present and no open requests.
[image: Program Blade loading]

When I refresh the page I sometimes get the following:
[image: Program Blade loaded]

I don't like the red icon but okay. I click the locator and get this:
[image: Locator Blade]

Clicking the blue box opens a new Blade with a generic error:
[image: error]
With the following error in the dev console:
[image: error log]

When trying to open the url from the Locator Blade or the Program Blade in VLC it doesn't open.

I once had the problems I'm having now, but a couple of days later they were resolved without action from my side.

Now I'm having the same problems again.

I tried recreating everything from scratch, but I get the same errors.

Comment: Do you have to use the Azure Portal to preview and playback the video? If you have a PC, I'd recommend installing and using https://aka.ms/amse. The preview output is available only in Smooth Streaming protocol, which requires that you have Flash or Silverlight plugin installed, per http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html#error-codes

Comment: I don't think that is correct because at the moment when everything worked fine, the preview played in the same browser I try to play it in now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment, it seems that all the problems were solved now.

Here is just my experience which may answer your question. I used to have the same issue, and finally I found that I need to start the stream endpoint. At least one stream  endpoint needs to be started before we can provide a video streaming service.

If you want to preview the live stream, you need to start the stream endpoint too, as all the stream content will be delivered from stream endpoints.

---

Update:

You can start a stream endpoint on the portal:

1. Navigate to your azure media service resource.
2. Click the "Streaming endpoints" label.
3. Then you will see all the streaming endpoints you have.
4. Choose one endpoint, and you can start or stop it in the showing page.

[image]

Comment: But I can't start the streaming endpoint because I get the blade with the error

Comment: Yes it's in the question "Clicking the blue box opens a new blade with a generic error" "Blade: StreamingEndpointDetailsBlade"

Comment: @YentheO This might be a logic bug of the Azure portal web page. But you can always manage endpoints at the streaming endpoints page. Check my update to see if it helps.

Comment: That indeed partially does the trick. The red dot next to the streaming locator turns green. And if I do watch in the Program blade, I get my live stream in the browser player. The preview still doesn't work though with the same error as before but that is not that important, I would also assume that the preview would work without going live first. When I just copy the link of the manifest to try out the demo player of ams, I get Video playback aborted. That get's fixed by adding https instead of http in front of the copied url.

Comment: I'm gonna mark your answer as correct because you because of you I can stream. Still strange that all those errors and things happen. Thanks!